# Is it possible to capture packets between two devices in a wifi

Tags: wireless, wireshark

I have little knowledge of how wifis work.

I have these:

1. A device which creates a wifi network when turned on. (Lets call this `DeviceA`)
2. A mobile app, when connected to the above wifi network, displays some stuff on the display. (Lets call this `DeviceB`)

I do not have any idea how these devices are communicating with each other (udp multicast, tcp, or combination)

I need to find out what data is passed between the two devices and how.

Is this possible?

So, right now it's like this:

```
DeviceA <=== some communication ===> DeviceB
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
             How to monitor this?
```

Or, is there a way to do this?

```
DeviceA <======> (A proxy?) <======> DeviceB
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
          So I can monitor traffic through here?
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to sniff the wireless packets.

You would need airpcap and a wireless adapter which is compatible with airpcap.Basically,an adapter which supports monitoring mode.

Google for the sniffing wireless packets using airpcap and you will get detailed guides.

If you wanna take it up further then I suggest you to install kali linux and get an Alfa card as wireless adapter.

You can filter using bsssid in wireshark to filter the router and client.